# How to send email message to two email id Address in zend Mail

Tags: zend-framework

Hi I am new in zend framework.

I have 2 email id's and i want to send message to 2 mail ids in zend mail

this is my code

```
$to1='abcd@gmail.com'
$to2='xyz@gmail.com'

 $mailObj = new Zend_Mail()

$mailObj->setSubject($subject)

mailObj->setBodyHtml($message)

$mailObj->addTo($to1, $name='test')

$mailObj->setFrom($from, $name = null)

$mailObj->send()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define receiver as an array, for example:

`$mailObj->addTo(array('address1@example.com', 'address2@example.com'), 'test');`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add Recipients using array like below

```
 $recipients = array('abcd@gmail.com','xyz@gmail.com')

 $message = new Zend_Mail();
    $message->setFrom('fake@email.com', 'My Fake Mailing List')
                                    ->setSubject($subject)
                                    ->setBodyText($body);

    foreach($recipients as $each_recipient){        
        $message->addTo($each_recipient);
    }

    $message->send();
```

for detail documentation you can check [Zend_Mail - adding recipients](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.adding-recipients.html)

let me know if i can help you more.